# What's the concise terminology for orbits which never cross?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

> What's the concise terminology for a pair of orbits which are orthogonal wherever they meet and each never crosses itself?

For example the white lines in this diagram:

[Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#/media/File:PrimitivePythagoreanTriplesRev08.svg)

I want to say one is monotonic with respect to the other but I have no idea of either the precise definition of what I'm describing or what the correct terminology is.

But let me be as precise as I can be.

Suppose we can arrange some integral points into an two-dimensional space which can be Euclidean for the sake of argument.  Suppose the orbit of one function $f^n(x)$ through these points plots multiple lines in one direction (one line for each $x$, and one point on each line for each $n$) which never cross each other, and another orbit say of a function $g^m(x)$ plots multiple lines in another direction again never crossing each other but orthogonal to the other orbits.

The term I really want to capture is the name for the property of these two orbits which determines that if both orbits are directed then I can never follow a loop among these two orbits because any such graph will be antisymmetric.

Comment: [Orthogonal trajectories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory)

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Please make it an answer and I can accept.